# How to add a navigation bar to WKWebView?

Tags: swift, navigationbar, wkwebview

I'm trying to implement an embedded webView using WKWebView. I have the initial configuration and with the following code I can load a web page into my storyboard.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

With this, I can see the web content inside my app, but there is not a navigation bar, and I need to allow users to enter a desired url. How can I add a navigation bar like any other web browser?

Answer (score 13):

Based on the suggested web [link](http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/) by Devran Cosmo, this is my final view controller code.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView
    @IBOutlet weak var barView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlField: UITextField!

    // Web Browser navigator
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var reloadButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    @IBAction func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if (self.webView.canGoBack) {
            self.webView.goBack()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func forward(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if (self.webView.canGoForward) {
            self.webView.goForward()
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
      }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,  withTransitionCoordinator coordinator:     UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        barView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: 30)
    }

    // Load user requested url
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        urlField.resignFirstResponder()
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlField.text)!))
        var list : WKBackForwardList = self.webView.backForwardList

        println("BACK LIST")
        println(list.backList)

        return false
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context:   UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) {
        if (keyPath == "loading") {
            backButton.enabled = webView.canGoBack
            forwardButton.enabled = webView.canGoForward
        }

        if (keyPath == "estimatedProgress") {
            progressView.hidden = webView.estimatedProgress == 1
            progressView.setProgress(Float(webView.estimatedProgress),  animated: true)
        }
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError!) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:  error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default,  handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.insertSubview(webView, belowSubview: progressView)

        webView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -44)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute:    .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1,    constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([height, width])

        // Disable navigation buttons on first loads
        backButton.enabled = false
        forwardButton.enabled = false

        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .New, context: nil)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.appcoda.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your main storyboard set up? I tried using this code but it just white pages.

Comment: WKWebView are programatically added so for starters I'd suggest you just add a normal view in your storyboard and add the wkwebview instance as subview to the view you added in storyboard. But for the more optimal way, you can use the init with frame function of the wkwebview and just manually input the x,y,width and height params.

Comment: @Mike Purcell probably you need to allow arbitrary load in your info.plist

Comment: Instead of allowing arbitrary loads for all requests, you can now use [NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent] (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW59)

Answer (score 5):

You have to wrap your `WebViewViewController` inside an `UINavigationController`. And add the elements (back button, refresh, location textfield) you need inside the navigationBar.

Which would look like this:

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: WebViewViewController())
```

**Example** (put this code in your AppDelegate):

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: WebViewViewController())
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

There's also a tutorial on how to create an iOS browser using Webkit on AppCoda.

Tutorial:
**http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/**

On that page, please see JFM's comment - the author of the tutorial made some mistakes :)

Comment: Thaks you, I take a break and foud this tutorial last night and work perfectly... I will paste my final code with the JFM's comment observations :)....

Comment: How do this if WebViewController ins't root?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 72, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height-72))
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    let configuration  = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    webview = WKWebView(frame : myView.frame , configuration : configuration)
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webview)
    webview.load(URLRequest(url : URL (string: url!)!))
    webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
}
```

I have design 72 px navigation bar and WKWebView set point (x:0,y:72),WkWebView frame is myView bounds

Comment: To help future developers… using a fixed y offset will be wrong on notch phones (iPhone X, XS, …) you need to use the view.safeAreaInsets.top to take account of the notch.